# Writing a wrapper class without copying or dereferencing

Tags: c++, c++11, wrapper

Suppose I want to create a wrapper around another class instance, but I don't want to move or copy that original class instance.  Maybe the instance I want to wrap is declared on the heap and lots of other stuff points to it.

I could do something like this:

```
class SomeClass {
 public:
  void Bar(int);
};

class Wrapper {
 public:
  Wrapper(SomeClass *some_class) {
    data = some_class;
  }

  void Foo() {
    data->Bar(42);
  }

 private:
  SomeClass *data;
};
```

However this adds a level of indirection, because the data pointer has to be dereferenced.  Compare to this implementation which would make a copy of SomeClass:

```
class Wrapper {
 public:
  Wrapper(SomeClass some_class) : data(some_class) {}

  void Foo() {
    data.Bar(42);
  }

 private:
  SomeClass data;
};
```

That avoids the dereference but now it's not a wrapper (plus the overhead of the copy).

Is there a way to write the wrapper in a way that avoids the dereference without copying or moving the wrapped object?

I was thinking you could do something like static casting a SomeClass instance to a Wrapper instance since the data layout of the two classes should be the same (since there's no vtable or extra data in the Wrapper class), but that would never get past a code review.

Comment: What if you change your first attempt's constructor to `Wrapper(SomeClass &some_class) {
    data = &some_class;
  }`? Not exactly safe, but if the caller will guarantee its lifetime is long enough, you're good.

Comment: Why not use reference then: `SomeClass &data; Wrapper(SomeClass &some_class): data(some_class)`?

Comment: Can you expand upon the need to "avoid the dereference?" What about the dereference bothers you?

Comment: Have you *measured* that the dereference and "extra indirection" is a bottleneck? Compilers are *very* good ad their own optimizations these days. First write good, well-written and documented and most of all *working* code. *Then* measure and profile to find the bottlenecks, and concentrate your efforts on the places where your non-premature optimizations requires the least coding-effort for the most performance.

Comment: Why is dereferencing bad?

Comment: The question literally answers itself in the same breath: no.

Comment: Your idea about a static cast is doomed to fail, since if the types are not related, then the cast cannot work. It couldn't work regardless of the type of cast you used, since you would be lying to the compiler that there was a live `Wrapper` at whatever address, but there wouldn't really be; that flouts the object model. Even besides all that, you'd have to take the address of the wrapped object and cast it to a wrapper (but again, you can't really!) every time you wanted to use it, which sounds no better than dereferencing to me. Basically, this is premature optimisation of the highest order

Comment: @AndyG and W.F.: Using references, while nicer semantically and syntactically, can't make any difference to OP's IMO misguided quest to avoid dereferencing, due to whatever theoretical performance hit they think it incurs. A reference member in an object is going to be implemented as a pointer by any practical compiler. Besides, even on a purely abstract level, both a pointer and a reference must be dereferenced to get at the referred object. How else would a reference work?

Comment: @underscore_d: I interpreted OP's post to mean that they didn't want the caller to have to say `Wrapper(&my_data)`; they want the syntax of `Wrapper(my_data)` without the copying.

Comment: @underscore_d Also in general const reference can be optimized by compiler... not sure if this can happen when non static fields are in a game but I think this may be a good start point for the OP to perform efficiency tests...

Comment: What you have is [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): You tell us about a solution you want help with to make it work, but you don't really tell us what the *problem* is that you want to solve. Perhaps if you elaborate on that (with an edit to your question) we might be able to help you better.

Comment: @Robᵩ - It's a matter of polluting the cache (and a little bit the extra instructions).  It's unlikely that the instance of Wrapper will be colocated next to the instance of SomeClass, so the cache line with Wrapper in it has to be loaded, the pointer to SomeClass found, and followed to another cache line to load up the data in SomeClass.  It's not an earth shattering issue, but avoiding the dereference does have some performance benefit in performance critical code.  Akin to how vtable lookups can become a performance bottleneck in some applications.

Comment: @underscore_d - It's obviously not kosher, but if the data layout of two structs are identical (and I mean *identical*, including the vtables) you can cast one to the other without issue.  Sort of like a union, but you don't tell the compiler about it.  Yes, a theoretical  compiler is free to layout the two classes in entirely different ways, so it's not a Good Idea, but in practice GCC and MSVC would lay them out the same and it would work.  It's very much a hacky idea from my C background and not a very C++ idea, but it would work, if you were very careful.  I wouldn't do it in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on an idea from @Frank, the compiler is smart enough to compile away the wrapper class if you declare it on the stack and let it inline everything.  This:

```
class SomeClass {
 public:
  void Bar(int bar) {
      data = bar;
  }
 private:
  int data;
};

int main() {
    SomeClass *instance = new SomeClass();
    instance->Bar(42);
}
```

produces the same assembly as this wrapper class (according to [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) with gcc 6.3 and -O3):

```
class SomeClass {
 public:
  void Bar(int bar) {
      data = bar;
  }
 private:
  int data;
};

class Wrapper {
 public:
  Wrapper(SomeClass *some_class) {
    data = some_class;
  }

  void Foo() {
    data->Bar(42);
  }

 private:
  SomeClass *data;
};

int main() {
    SomeClass *instance = new SomeClass();
    Wrapper wrapper(instance);
    wrapper.Foo();
}
```

But this produces extra assembly (even beyond the call to 'new'):

```
class SomeClass {
 public:
  void Bar(int bar) {
      data = bar;
  }
 private:
  int data;
};

class Wrapper {
 public:
  Wrapper(SomeClass *some_class) {
    data = some_class;
  }

  void Foo() {
    data->Bar(42);
  }

 private:
  SomeClass *data;
};

int main() {
    SomeClass *instance = new SomeClass();
    Wrapper *wrapper = new Wrapper(instance);
    wrapper->Foo();
}
```

So as long as the wrapper class is constructed on the stack in a way that the compiler can optimize it away there's no performance overhead.  If the wrapper class gets declared on the heap it can't make that optimization.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to write the wrapper in a way that avoids the dereference without copying or moving the wrapped object?

I can't think of any.

When you write a wrapper, you have two choices. You either make a copy or store a reference (either a pointer and reference, i.e. `SomeClass&`).

I would recommend using a reference. Syntactically, the reference can be used just like as though you had made a copy. I wouldn't worry about the cost of the actual dereferencing (after all, a reference is still a pointer under the covers) at run time unless it becomes prohibitive in your use case.

```
class Wrapper {
  public:
    Wrapper(SomeClass& some_class) : data(some_class) {}

    void Foo() {
      data.Bar(42);
    }

  private:
    SomeClass& data;
};
```

With this approach, the wrapper will be good to use as long as the object it references outlives the wrapper. If the wrapper outlives the main object, you will run into a dangling reference problem.

Comment: The problem with this is, of course, if the wrapper object outlives the wrapped object. But then that's a problem with the plain pointer case as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you want to avoid dereferencing so much, as, at the end of the day, a memory access is a memory access.  The fact that it's on the stack (and you access it with the `.` operator) or on the heap (`->` operator) is largely irrelevant.

To make the point, here's a simple bit of code:

```
class foo {
    public:
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    foo f1;
    f1.a = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

And its corresponding assembly:

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp 
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], 0 // f1.a = 0
mov     eax, 0 
pop     rbp
ret
```

Compare it to:

```
class foo {
    public:
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    foo *f2 = new foo();
    f2->a = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

With assembly:

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
sub     rsp, 16
mov     edi, 4
call    operator new(unsigned long)
mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 0
mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8] // Address of f2
mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 0     // f2->a = 0
mov     eax, 0
leave
ret
```

At the end of the day, you have one extra assembly instruction (in this unoptimized for clarity sake's example), and that is because in the first version you can just offset from the stack pointer and need to load the address in the 2nd version.  There will be absolutely no noticeable effect from this at runtime, especially as when you are doing multiple access you'll have one address load that then gets offset for all of the following accesses.

Don't micro-optimize things that don't matter.

Comment: I appreciate your take, but I wanted to correct one of your misconceptions.  -> and . don't mean heap and stack respectively.  It's entirely possible to dereference with -> from an object declared on the stack, and entirely possible to use . for objects declared on the heap.

Comment: re: the performance penalty, there are embedded systems where the added overhead of even a vtable lookup can bubble up to the top of a performance profile of a critical inner loop.  Whether this is one of those situations is sort of orthogonal to the question asked.  But yes, profile first, etc. etc.

Comment: @JayLemmon - These are both fair comments, I was speaking most commonly / generally, since we have pretty much no details.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is no for a human, yes for a compiler.

You cannot write a wrapper that does what you describe.

However, take your `Wrapper` class . Ther compiler is free to optimize away that indirection if it can make the right assumptions.

For example:

```
inline void foo(Wrapper x) {
  x.Foo();
}

int main() {
  auto v = std::make_unique<SomeClass>();
  Wrapper tmp(v.get();
  foo(tmp);
}
```

I'd bet dollar to donuts you wouldn't pay for dereferencing the wrapper here.

Comment: Define how you "pay for dereferencing" please.

Comment: You can only say "yes for a compiler" if you have evidence. "Ther complier is free to" and "I'd bet" don't count.

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  Basically declare the wrapper on the stack and rely on the inline function unwinding to basically never actually instantiate an instance of Wrapper.  You still dereference to SomeClass (no real way around that after all), but the "wrapper" overhead should compile away entirely.